# How to add X-Forwarded-For Request Header in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am setting up a performance test with load I have set of 100 GET requests sample request as below:

`http://34.202.108.112:8080/adserver/html5/inwapads/?sleepAfter=0&adFormat=preappvideo&ak=c39ca252e3605ca216f05d4c6ed18b08&version=1.0&fullscreen=1&vdo=1&requester=dashbid&channelType=site&pageURL=http%3A%2F%2Fibtimes.co.uk&siteName=ibtimes.co.uk&refURL=ibtimes.co.uk&*ipAddress=212.232.34.134*&ua=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+Android+5.0.1%3B+SCH-R970+Build%2FLRX22C%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F47.0.2526.83+Mobile+Safari%2F537.36&cb=1477379953087252374&target_params=latlong=57.6198/39.8554|geoType=1&size=x&dnt=0&output=vast;vdocookieid=af7d5dc67d7cd4e9f4a56f09d0b1046b 2351daf4-3fb3-4d5c-890c-c32672e036df 35c720f4-5bb3-45f3-b5b1-be9fcd5f2f5d`

All set of requests have different `ipAddress` , What I want to add `X-Forwarded-For` Request Header for each request which has value same as `ipAddress` in request .

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting these IP addresses from CSV file you can just add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) and configure it like:

[image: JMeter add request header]

---

If you have 100 requests with hard-coded IP addresses (i.e. coming from recording) it is still possible, but you will need to do some scripting

1. Add HTTP Header Manager to your Test Plan (same level as the HTTP Request samplers)
2. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to your Test Plan (same level as the HTTP Request samplers)
3. Put the following code into JSR223 PreProcessor "Script" area

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header

   def address = sampler.getArguments().getArgumentsAsMap().get("ipAddress")
   def headerManager = sampler.getHeaderManager()
   headerManager.removeHeaderNamed("X-Forwarded-For")
   headerManager.add(new Header("X-Forwarded-For", address))
   ```

The above code will look for `ipAddress` request parameter and if it will be found it will add the relevant `X-Forwarded-For` header to the request

Comment: How to validate that after setting above jmeter is sending xff in request when we apply load?

Comment: Variable is not replaced ? Am i missing something?

Comment: Please let me know if I am missing something this does not work , variable in xff is not replaced

Comment: @Mayankpandey If you are sending 100 requests in GUI, you can view the request headers in the `View Results Tree` listener. If you are executing tests in non-GUI, you can load the JTL file in the `View Results Tree` listener.